# Swizzling causing recursion

Tags: swift, swizzling

So when I tried to swizzle `UIImage`'s `init(named:)` so that I could set the accessibility identifier with the image's name, it seems like, even though I am calling `method_exchangeImplementation`, both my swizzled method `ftg_imageNamed(named name: String)` and `init(named:)` call my swizzled method: `ftg_imageNamed(named name: String)` creating an infinite loop.  Why is that?

Calling `method_exchangeImplementation`

```
extension UIImage {

    static func swizzleInitImplementation() {
        let originalSelector =  #selector(UIImage.init(named:))
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIImage.ftg_imageNamed(named:))


        let imgSelf: AnyClass = self.classForCoder()

        guard  let originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(imgSelf, originalSelector),
            let swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(imgSelf, swizzledSelector) else {
                assertionFailure("The methodsw are not found")
                return
        }

        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }

    @objc static func ftg_imageNamed(named name: String)  {
        setAccessibilityLabel(name)
        self.ftg_imageNamed(named: name)
    }

}
```

The manual implementation which failed the same way.

```
extension UIImage {

    static func swizzleInitImplementation() {
        let originalSelector =  #selector(UIImage.init(named:))
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIImage.ftg_imageNamed(named:))


        let imgSelf: AnyClass = self.classForCoder()

        guard  let originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(imgSelf, originalSelector),
            let swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(imgSelf, swizzledSelector) else {
                assertionFailure("The methodsw are not found")
                return
        }

        let imp1 = method_getImplementation(originalMethod)
        let imp2 = method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod)
        method_setImplementation(originalMethod, imp2)
        method_setImplementation(swizzledMethod, imp1)

    }

    @objc static func ftg_imageNamed(named name: String)  {
        setAccessibilityLabel(name)
        self.ftg_imageNamed(named: name)
    }

}
```

Comment: what is `self.UI(named: name)`?

Comment: fixed.  @vikingosegundo, did you downvote because of a typo?

Comment: You are calling the `ftg_imageNamed` method from itself while swizzling. There, your reason for recursion.

Comment: @x4h1d, as I understand it, when you swizzle, you are telling the compiler to call method 2 when it says to call method 1 and call method 1 when it says to call method 2. https://trinhngocthuyen.github.io/2017-10-20-method-swizzling-what-why-and-how.html. Accordingly, recursion should not occur.

Comment: yes, that's after executing `swizzleInitImplementation`, **not at the state of implementing `swizzleInitImplementation`**. When you call `swizzleInitImplementation`, it will call `ftg_imageNamed`. As swizzling is not implemented yet, `self.ftg_imageNamed(named: name)` will call itself. Hence, recursion.

Comment: It doesn't call `ftg_imageNamed` when I call `swizzleInitImplementation`.  It does, however, call `ftg_imageNamed` when I call the `UIImage(named:)` initializer later on.

Comment: I didnt downvote it because of a typo. I downvoted it because that typo made it impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, thank you for the undo.

Comment: I want to highlight that in contrast to Objective-C `inits` aren't regular functions. they aren't typed `func`, also they don't have a return statement. I don't know what consequences that has for swizzling, but I wouldn't expect them to behave nicely.

Comment: @vikingosegundo.  Really good point, I was wondering about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your swizzling seems "**ok**" until `self.UI(named: name)`. So check that method for infinite loop problem.

Now, this is a bad implementation of swizzling. `UIImage.init(named:)` returns an instance of `UIImage`, where swizzled method `UIImage.ftg_imageNamed(named:)` returns `Void`. Both original and swizzled method should have the same params and return type, the implementation may vary.

You should consider a simple extension method to achieve what you want instead of swizzling.

**Edit**

```
extension UIImage {
    static func initIncludingAccessibility(named: String) -> UIImage {
       let img = UIImage(named: named)
       img.setAccessibilityLabel(named)
       return img
    }
}
```

use it as

```
let image = UIImage.initIncludingAccessibility(named: /* your_image_name*/)
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  `You should consider a simple extension method to achieve what you want instead of swizzling.` I'm all ears.  How can I do that?

Comment: For that, we need to know what do you want to achieve.

Comment: When a `UIImage` is instantiated, I want the accessibility identifier to automatically be set as equal to the image asset name.

Comment: Ah, this would require all the initialization of `UIImage` to change.  I want this change to happen without changing the current code.

Comment: *Make Simple Tasks Simple!* - Bjarne Stroustrup. Best of luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186614/discussion-between-scottyblades-and-x4h1d).

Comment: @ScottyBlades did u able to avoid infiite loop ?

Comment: It’s best to avoid swizzling.  IMO swizzling is a very bad practice because you set up other developers to be surprised when they use the function.  Also you make a subtle mistake you risk run time errors such as infinite loops and unexpected behaviors.  It’s better to create a new function and use that, or have ci give a warning when using certain functions or deprecating.